# How to callback into React Component state from inner HTML?

Tags: reactjs

I know this won't be a great question but I don't see any other choice. I'm using the Frappe Gantt chart library from a React wrapper (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-frappe-gantt)

I modified react-frappe-gantt to pass through `custom_popup_html` to allow for a custom form. The goal is to allow a user to "Add Milestone" from a toolbar, then from a milestone in the Gantt chart the user clicks it, sees a popup with some details and a "Add Action" button that will callback into my React Component state to display the full "Add Action" modal.

The problem is that Frappe Gantt only accepts an HTML string as a value to custom_popup_html. And the button would be inside that string.

Here's an example:

```
handleActionPopup(task) {
   return `
      <div class='details-container'>
         <h5>${task.name}</h5>
         <button onclick="console.log('Add action')">Add Action</button>
      </div>
   `
}

...

render() {
   ...
   <Gantt
      tasks={tasks}
      customPopupHtml={(task) => this.handleActionPopup(task) }
   />
}
```

The console will of course show the click action, but I need to it callback into the component in some way.

I can't attach a ref as far as I can tell because this isn't JSX rendered objects, it has to be a HTML string.

I'd be ok with the JS setting or firing some DOM event that my React component listens to. It's not great but using Frappe is more valuable than avoiding a hack.

How can I attach/listen/callback/call the React Component from the button's click event? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

K I worked out a method to handle this by assigning the Component function to the window in componentDidMount() and calling it from the inner HTML, then removing it from the window in componentWillUnmount(). It's not great but clean

```
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Component } from 'react'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    test: 'uninitialized'
  }

  tasks = [
    {
      id: 'Task 1',
      name: 'Redesign website',
      start: '2016-12-28',
      end: '2016-12-31',
      progress: 10,
      dependencies: ''
    },
    {
      id: 'Task 2',
      name: 'Redesign website 2',
      start: '2016-12-28',
      end: '2016-12-31',
      progress: 20,
      dependencies: 'Task 1'
    }
  ]

  testFunc = txt => {
    this.setState({ test: txt })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.testFunc = this.testFunc
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    delete window.testFunc
  }

  handleActionPopup(task) {
    return `
      <div class='details-container'>
         <h5>${task.name}</h5>
         <button onclick="window.testFunc('${task.name}')">Add Action</button>
      </div>
      `
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.test}</div>
        <Gantt
          tasks={this.tasks}
          customPopupHtml={task => this.handleActionPopup(task)}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function Gantt(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.tasks.map(task => (
        <button
          key={task.name}
          onClick={() => {
            const popupHtml = props.customPopupHtml(task)
            const wrapperForPopup = document.querySelector('#wrapperForPopup')

            wrapperForPopup.innerHTML = popupHtml
          }}
        >
          {task.name}
        </button>
      ))}

      <div id="wrapperForPopup" style={{ marginTop: 30 }} />
    </div>
  )
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

If anyone has an alternative I'm all ears (and eyes).

Comment: I dont have any alternatives, but this is exactly what i needed! Thank you!